# in odoo16, how to call python function via web frontend owl side?

Tags: odoo-16

I defined a function in model account.move as below:

```
def justtest(self):
    print('hello, account.move')
```

and in owl side, in the xxx.js file, I defined another button function:

```
test(){
    this._rpc({
                        model: "account.move",
                        method: 'justtest',
                    });
}
```

when I clicked button on the web page, the system warn: _rpc is not a function.
how to call the python ? thanks.